# Simple software low pass filter

Tags: lowpass-filter, filtering, software-implementation

I am measuring voltages and currents of a 3-phase electrical machine and I need to calculate the power. Every interrupt (frequency between 30-70kHz) I get values (voltages, currents) from analogue-digital converter and I need to do a simple calculation to determine power. However, I was told to use averaging with a first order filter with a time constant of approximate 1s for the power calculation. This, I believe, means low pass filter with a frequency of approximately 1Hz? What is the simplest solution to this? Moving average?

Answer (score 6):

A first order lowpass filter is usually implemented like this:

$$p[n] = \alpha p[n-1] + (1-\alpha) pi[n]$$

Where $p[n]$ is your filtered power estimation, $p[n-1]$ is the previous result, $pi[n]$ is your new measurement (probably the product of instantaneous voltage and current measurements), and $\alpha$ is a positive parameter just less than 1.

The nearer $\alpha$ gets to 1, the larger the time constant (lower cutoff frequency) of your filter. But beware, especially in embedded systems with limited precision, that getting too near to 1 can make your filter unstable, or at least have problems due to numerical precision.

The [cutoff frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Simple_infinite_impulse_response_filter) for that filter is around $f_s \frac{1-\alpha}{2\pi\alpha}$, where $f_s$ is your sampling frequency.

Comment: There must be a mistake in the formula for cutoff freq ($\alpha/(1-\alpha)$ is much larger than 1 if $\alpha$ is close to but less than 1, no?   I think it is $\frac{1-\alpha}{2\pi \alpha}$

Comment: Thanks, this looks similar to the solution at the bottom of this page: https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2015/10/tutorial-potentiometers-with-arduino-and-filtering/

Comment: However, your equation states that current measured value needs to be multiplied by (1-alpha) and previous value with alpha, while on the page above, this is vice versa. Which is correct? Also, which equation for cutoff frequency is correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: $\alpha$ happens to be the **pole** location of this simple LPF.  i would recommend that $\alpha$ be very close to 1, but less than 1. $$ 0 < 1-\alpha \ll 1 $$.  and $pi[n]$ is the instantaneous power at time $n$ and is the product of the instantaneous voltage and instantaneous current as measured by the separate A/D converters.  this is necessary to measure *real* power in a reactive situation.

Comment: OK, but in this case, do I have to multiply pi[n] with alpha or with (1 - alpha)? Which is the correct equation for cutoff frequency?

Comment: @Juancho Could you comment cut-off frequency equation?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Could you tell me if equation for cut-off frequency is the same for this case? https://www.norwegiancreations.com/2015/10/tutorial-potentiometers-with-arduino-and-filtering/